# How to loop over through columns of a table and based on the column name, I want to fetch values based on the column name from other table

Tags: mysql, sql-server

**Table 1**

```
| Id | ProductName | Is_JAipur | Is_Rajasthan | Is_Nagpur |
|----|-------------|-----------|--------------|-----------|
|  1 |         101 |         0 |            1 |         0 |
|  2 |         102 |         0 |            0 |         1 |
```

**Table 2**

```
| Id |      Name |
|----|-----------|
|  1 |    Jaipur |
|  2 | Rajasthan |
|  3 |    Nagpur |
```

**Table 3**

```
| Id | Product | City |
|----|---------|------|
|  1 |     101 |    2 |
|  2 |     102 |    3 |
```

I want to write a query to get the `Id` from `table 2` while looping through `table 1` column. and insert in `table 3`. I want to keep this dynamic since city may increase in the future.

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: Better change your table structure of `Table1` like (`Id,ProductName,cityID`). `cityID` will refer to `Table2.Id` and you won't need `Table3` unless it's one to many relationship.

Comment: "I want to write a query" - what's stopping you?

Comment: @Mitch Thanks! The table 1 structure I can't change its coming from a fixed data source that I haven't control moreover It has also one to many relationships. My expected output is to get the Id of respective city from table 2(which are set 1 in table 1)  and insert these values in table 3

Comment: @PrasunSingh: show expected output. look here on how to frame questionhttps://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @TheGameiswar I have already explained that I want to insert Table 3 with the data shown based on table 1 and table 2 hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've already mentioned the required change in your table design. Unless you adopt this you will face bigger problems in future.

Nevertheless, I am giving you the solution on your current requirement:

```
INSERT INTO your_table_3(Product,City)

SELECT 
t.ProductName,
your_table_2.Id
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
    ProductName,
    CASE WHEN is_JAipur = 1 THEN 'Jaipur' 
             WHEN Is_Rajasthan = 1 THEN 'Rajasthan'
             WHEN Is_Nagpur = 1 THEN 'Nagpur' END AS cityName
    FROM your_table_1 
) AS t
INNER JOIN your_table_2 ON t.cityName = your_table_2.`Name`
```

<kbd>[**WORKING DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/654e8/1/0)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, But I don't want to hardcode the value of columns names in script since the city names may increase in future I have already explored this option.  I want to iterate through the column (which contains city name) of table 1 find the Id from table 2 and insert Id and product name in table 3.

Comment: Your solution works fine but not what I am exploring on, its something dynamic (y)

Comment: Sorry mate. I cannot make this worse.